# How to extract span in re.finditer method in python?

Tags: python, python-re

the results of re.finditer is as below.

```
[i for i in result]
=[<re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='sin theta '>,
 <re.Match object; span=(12, 18), match='cos x '>,
 <re.Match object; span=(20, 26), match='e ^ x '>,
 <re.Match object; span=(26, 32), match='f( x )'>,
 <re.Match object; span=(37, 45), match='log_ {x}'>]
```

Here, I used the code i.span instead of i, but I just got something as below.

```
[<function Match.span(group=0, /)>,
 <function Match.span(group=0, /)>,
 <function Match.span(group=0, /)>,
 <function Match.span(group=0, /)>,
 <function Match.span(group=0, /)>]
```

I'm gonna extract span in re.finditer.
like (0,10), (12,18), ...

Help me please!

I defined the function for getting re.finditer
The code is as below.

```
import re
def convert_ftn_to_token(seq):
    va = '[a-z]{1,}'

    ftn_lst = ['sin','cos','tan','log_', 'e ?\^'] 
    ftn_lst = [ftn + ' ?\{? ?' + va +' ?\}?' for ftn in ftn_lst]
    ftn_lst2  = [chr(i) for i in range(65,91)] + [chr(i) for i in range(97,123)]
    ftn_lst2 = [ftn + ' ?\( ?' + va + ' ?\)' for ftn in ftn_lst2]


    ftn_c = re.compile(
        '|'.join(ftn_lst2) +'|'+
        '|'.join(ftn_lst)
    )

    return re.finditer(ftn_c,seq)
```

i.span for i in results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.span` is a method, not an attribute. You want `.span()` which will give the start, end tuple.

Comment: It's also an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `start()` and `end()` in regex's `Match` object, [documentation about it here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects). They correspond to the lower and upper bound of `span` respectively. As for the grouping stated in the docs, that only applies if you are intending to use the grouping functionality of `Match`. If you intend to get the span of the entire match, you can simply do `match.start()` and `match.end()`, where `match` is the match object returned by the regex.

Another option is using `span()` of the same `Match` object. Note this is different from just `span` which will give you the memory address rather than actually call the function. Doing `match.span()` will give you a tuple of the start and end. Taking your first match object as an example this would return `(0,10)`

Comment: Thanks for answer. but when I use start or end method, the result is 
`[<function Match.end(group=0, /)>,
 <function Match.end(group=0, /)>,
 <function Match.end(group=0, /)>,
 <function Match.end(group=0, /)>,
 <function Match.end(group=0, /)>]` the same.

Comment: @junsulee **you need to call these methods**. You aren't calling them.

Comment: are you doing it with the brackets as `start()` or just `start`? Although slightly different from what I expect to see, it looks like the output is a function pointer rather than the function result which can occur if the function isn't invoked. You want to include the `()`.